# vim: insert at beginning of block not working

Tags: linux, vim

I'm trying to add to the beginning of lines in vim with `Ctrl-V` then `Shift + i` and `Esc`. Except instead of ending up with

```
#1
#2
#3
```

I get

```
#1
2
3
```

`:echo has('visualextra')` returns a 1 and I'm not sure where the issue is. I am also on the most recent version of vim.

Comment: Did you type `#` character before `Esc`?

Comment: Does it work when you start with `gvim -u NONE`? You could verify if you have a mapping with `I`. Other than that, I would start commenting half of my _vimrc and try to find the offending line.

Comment: yes I typed `#` and checking my vimrc now

Comment: And you do select all three lines: `<C-V>2jI#<Esc>`, right?

Answer (score 1):

I generally use vim substitute for this:

```
ESC + :1,$s/^/#/
```

You can also grab a specific set of lines with shift + v, then hit : and follow up with the substitution.

If you want to use column selection with Ctrl-V and then insert with Shift + i you need to hit ESC twice to replicate the change to all the rows.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you absolutely do not need to hit ESC twice.  There is a delay after hitting ESC due to the way special keys like the arrow keys are handled at a very low level, but after this delay the changes are made to all lines as expected.  Pressing ESC a second time just tells vim that you aren't pressing one of these special keys and immediately makes the change.